# How to fake ScanResponse?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, fakeiteasy

I am writing Unit test cases for getting the records from Dynamodb. Dynamodb is returning scanResponse. I want to fake ScanResponse. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you're using the AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 Nuget package)

You don't fake the `ScanResponse`; you fake the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` class (or better, the `IAmazonDynamoDB` interface; interfaces are less trouble to fake), and you configure its `ScanAsync` method to return the desired `ScanResponse`.

```
var dynamoDb = A.Fake<IAmazonDynamoDb>();
A.CallTo(() => dynamoDb.ScanAsync(A<ScanRequest>._, A<CancellationToken>._))
    .Returns(new ScanResponse
    {
        // Define the ScanResponse you want the method to return
        ...
    });
```